# Get all object with empty set of related ones

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I've got two models:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
    show = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Foo(models.Model):
    rel = generic.GenericRelation(Content)
```

And I want to get all Foo methods that's related content object (there would be only one) has `show==True` or that doesn't have related object at all. Something like:

```
Foo.objects.filter(Q(rel__show=True) | Q(rel__hasnone=True))
```

But of course there's nothing like `hasnone` in django.

Is there any other way in which I can accomplish that (unfortunately aggregation doesn't work with generic relations and I can't count items).

Comment: I saw your answer below, but here's a simpler thought: loop through the related sets and append all objects that have a related record to a list. Then, loop through the model again, and skip all records that are in the list.

This would be slower, but have the benefit of sticking entirely with python and the Django ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've answer that could satisfy some of us (unfortunately not me).

What I need was LEFT OUTER JOIN which Django doesn't support (all joins declared by user are INNER ones), something like:

```
SELECT *, `foobar_bar`.`show` AS `show` FROM `foobar_foo` LEFT OUTER JOIN `foobar_bar` 
    ON (`foobar_foo`.`id` = `foobar_bar`.`object_id` and 
        ctype = `foobar_bar`.`content_type_id`) 
    WHERE show=TRUE OR show=NULL
```

I assumed that both models are in `foobar` application and ctype is content_type of model `Foo`. I haven't found way to do such query but we can do something like:

```
SELECT *, `foobar_bar`.`show` AS `show` FROM `foobar_foo` LEFT OUTER JOIN `foobar_bar` 
    ON (`foobar_foo`.`id` = `foobar_bar`.`object_id`
    WHERE (show=TRUE OR show=NULL) AND ctype = `foobar_bar`.`content_type_id`
```

It's not satisfactory exclusive (could join tuples with different ctype just basing on object's id) but is still useful. Way to do such query I found at [link text](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/). It'll be something like:

```
qs = Foo.objects.all()

qs.query.join((None, 'foobar_foo', None, None))
qs.query.join(('foobar_foo', 'foobar_bar', 'id', 'object_id'), promote=True)
foos.
qs = qs.extra(select = {'show': 'foobar_bar.show',},
              where = "(show=TRUE OR show=NULL) AND ctype = `foobar_bar`.`content_type_id`")
```

Generally using `query.join((,), promote=True)` gets us LEFT QUERY JOIN instead of INNER, but we can pass only one ON argument, which is too less to solve completely that problem but still useful.